# Cypress tests removing certain attributes from the page

Tags: error-handling, cypress

Has anyone faced this with  Cypress?
When I run my test using cypress, a particular test, keeps failing because hidden element is not showing up but when I run the same test manually, I can see the element with the hidden element showing up as soon as I enter value.

There is a field in our UI where if I pass invalid characters, then it should immediately show the hidden error element using aria, but this is not happening when running through cypress.

Desired behavior
When I run the same above test manually on the same field the result I am getting is this.

Cypress test Result:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Actual Result:
[image]
[image]

Code :
[image]
[image]

Comment: Add the code you tried along with the error that you are getting.

Comment: Isn't the ID in your cypress get method incorrect? You have cy.get('#address-cityNameError') but in the screenshot above the ID seems to be address-cityNameHolder.

Comment: No, There is another ID which I am using, Updated the screenshots

Comment: Have you tried using `.blur()` after typing? `cy.get('foo').type('bar').blur()`?

Answer (score 0):

I think with `<pvd-system-message>` you have a `shadow-root` preventing access to the text inside you element.

Try

```js
cy.get('#address-cityNameError')                        
  .should('have.attr', 'message')               
  .shadow()                                                // inside shadow-root
  .should('contain', 'City contains invalid characters')
```

In case there are other tests with this problem, add `includeShadowDom` option to your config.

Ref [Configuration options](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Options)

**cypress.config.js**

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:1234',
    includeShadowDom: true
  }
})
```